# Posting user data to database

Tags: php

I am having an issue getting my form to post to the database. The first part is a query which checks CustomerID from one table, and this part works fine. The next part is to post the values to a different table. Everything works fine on the form but it is not posting to the "orders" table, and is not returning any errors. What am I missing?

```
<?php
    //Insert Into database
    $mysqli = @ new mysqli('127.0.0.1','root',null,'storefront');

    if (mysqli_connect_error())
    {
    echo 'Error: Could not connect to database. Please try again later.';
    exit;
    }

    $mysqli->select_db("storefront")
        or die("<p>Unable to select the database.</p>"
        ."<p>Error code ". mysqli_errno($mysqli)
        .": " . mysqli_error($mysqli)) . "</p>";

    $customerid = isset($_POST['customerid']);
    $custid = $_POST['customerid'];

    if($customerid)
    {
        $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM customer WHERE customerID = '$custid'");
        $row = $result->fetch_row();

        if (!$row)
        {
            echo "Customer Number not found.".mysql_error();
            exit;
        }
    }
    else
    {

        $tableName = "orders";
        $nullstr = "NULL";

        $SQLstring = "INSERT INTO $tableName VALUES
                ('".$nullstr."','".$customerid."', '".$blue."','".$green."','".$red."')";
        $result = $mysqli->query($SQLstring);   

        if ($result)
        {
            echo $mysqli->affected_rows ."  $tableName database.<br />";

            $mysqli->close();
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Have you tried echoing out `$SQLstring` to check to make sure it is a valid query? Also, where are you setting `$blue`, `$green`, and `$red`?

Comment: The query for the first part works, The second part "after the else{" is to post those values that are input on the previous page into a separate table.

Comment: y are you appending use prepared statements .

Comment: and if I take out the query for the customer table, and leave just the insert into orders, the info posts to the databas

Comment: Check my answer. I think it's cause your insert is in the wrong else. Also, listen to arun - prepared statements are there for a reason.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
$SQLstring = "INSERT INTO $tableName VALUES
            ('".$nullstr."','".$customerid."', '".$blue."','".$green."','".$red."')";
```

should be something like

```
$SQLstring = "INSERT INTO $tableName VALUES
            ('".$nullstr."','".$custid."', '".$blue."','".$green."','".$red."')";
```

Your insert is being called in the ELSE for `if($customerid)` - it looks like you intended that to be the else for the first query:

```
    if($customerid)
    {
        $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM customer WHERE customerID = '$custid'");
        $row = $result->fetch_row();

        if (!$row)
        {
            echo "Customer Number not found.".mysql_error();
            exit;
        }      
        else
        {
            $tableName = "orders";
            $nullstr = "NULL";

            $SQLstring = "INSERT INTO $tableName VALUES
                ('".$nullstr."','".$custid."', '".$blue."','".$green."','".$red."')";
            $result = $mysqli->query($SQLstring);   

            if ($result)
            {
                echo $mysqli->affected_rows ."  $tableName database.<br />";

                $mysqli->close();
            }
        }
    }
```

$blue, $green and $red aren't defined anywhere but that's not related.

Maybe I just missed the idea of your intentions here. If so, let me know and I will review again and update.

Comment: They are defined, this is just a portion of the page where I had the query for customerid from the customer table which works fine, but the part under the else is not posting.

Comment: I mean to have this as 2 different tasks, the query, and then the post to orders after it

Comment: It would be 2 different tasks, but aside that, if isset($customerid) returns false what are you inserting into the database? It looks like it would be an empty row. your values would be NULL, 0, $blue, $green, $red

Comment: Ok I am starting to follow you. The customerid is pulled from the customers table, and I was trying to post that into the orders table as a foreign key.

Comment: right, so the insert should only happen if the first select query returns a result. I updated my answer with what I expected it to look like - roughly

Comment: YES! That's what I've been looking for. Thanks so much for the help, nice to finally have this finished.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

`$customerid` to `$custid`

From

```
('".$nullstr."','".$customerid."', '".$blue."','".$green."','".$red."')";
```

To

```
('".$nullstr."','".$custid."', '".$blue."','".$green."','".$red."')";
```